# Bootstrap very simple col-12 inside container but not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

my question is very simple, I wanna lay 4 buttons in 1 line and it's working in PC but not working in phone:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-theme">Scores</button>
      <button class="btn btn-theme">With Lifetime Income</button>
      <button class="btn btn-theme">Without Lifetime Income</button>
      <button class="btn btn-theme">Bank</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see the 4 buttons are always fill in half row. not filling in entire row, why? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't reproducible. What is `btn-theme`?

Comment: It's just .btn-theme {
  background: #01b1d7 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
 should be good

Answer (score 0):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hmz777/pen/GRqdBbY). Wrap your buttons with a div and apply the following css: `display:flex;` and `justify-content: space-evenly;` on the defined container.

```css
.custom-cont {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="custom-cont">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Scores</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">With Lifetime Income</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Without Lifetime Income</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Bank</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Additionally you can use `flex: 1;` on your buttons to make them fill their entire available space when on a large screen:

SASS:

```
.custom-cont {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  
  button {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: not working, the 4 buttons are in the same line, but they still only fill in half screen

Comment: @Invincible_Pain Did you try `flex:1` on the buttons? see the [codepen](https://codepen.io/hmz777/pen/GRqdBbY).

Comment: @Invincible_Pain You can also use the `container-fluid` instead of `container` to make the div fill the screen.

Comment: <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
        <button class="btn btn-theme" style="flex: 1;">Scores</button>
        <button class="btn btn-theme" style="flex: 1;">With Lifetime Income</button>
        <button class="btn btn-theme" style="flex: 1;">Without Lifetime Income</button>
        <button class="btn btn-theme" style="flex: 1;">Bank</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

I tried above like you said and even container-fluid, but still the same

Comment: @Invincible_Pain I tried your code and  its working. keep in mind that `container` and `col-12` have padding and can be removed. See the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/hmz777/pen/GRqdBbY).